# How to Debug.Log a custom class

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

I have a custom class in C# for Unity, which contains multiple ints.

```
public class MyVector2Int
{

    public int x;
    public int y;

    public MyVector2Int(int xget, int yget)
    {
        x = xget;
        y = yget;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(MyVector2Int obj)
    {
        return "(" + obj.x + "," + obj.y + ")";
    }
}
```

However when I Debug.Log my class, I don't get desired result:

```
void MyFunction()
{
MyVector2Int v;
    v=new MyVector2Int(3,4);
    Debug.Log("Result:"+v);   // --> Expected Result:(3,4)
                              // --> Getting  Result:MyVector2Int
}
```

How can I update my class to display the expected result ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be overwriting the `ToString()` method, not create an implicit type conversion:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return "(" + obj.x + "," + obj.y + ")";
}
```